# Java cannot find symbol compile issue

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Hello all I am pretty sure I am being dumb but I can not figure out this compile issue. I am using VSCODE IDE and compiling some java files inside a folder as seen in the picture below. I don't understand why I am getting this error as all the files are in the same folder and all have the "package Lab2;" as seen in the main class here. Please and thanks for the help![image: ![VS Code IDE display]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqC76.png)

Comment: Here is an imgur link for the photo https://i.imgur.com/0go8yUK.png

Comment: PLEASE do not post images of your code.  Copy and paste the relevant text (code) into the question.

Comment: I mean the code is most likely not the issue here. I think it must be formating or how i structure the folder. I can list all 1k lines of code if you want but I doubt that would help.